# Host network and systemd not possible with podman 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: systemd, podman

I've recently updated to Ubuntu 22.04 from Ubuntu 20.04, and the containers I used to run with the command `podman run -it --rm --net host myimage /sbin/init` now fail with the following error:

> Failed to create /init.scope control group: Permission denied
> Failed to allocate manager object: Permission denied
> [!!!!!!] Failed to allocate manager object.
> Exiting PID 1...

Using the host network sharing alone (ie `--net host` and `/bin/bash` as command) or systemd alone (`/sbin/init`) works fine.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A podman update solved the problem. Went from v3.4.2 in the standard ubuntu repos to the 4.3.1 version available on the Kubic project ([here](https://software.opensuse.org//download.html?project=devel%3Akubic%3Alibcontainers%3Aunstable&package=podman)).

Note that i had to manually download the deb file & install it, the 'Add procedure and install manually' procedure doesn't work.